# How to pass php variable to another page in href onclick button tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I currently have a code where I want to pass a variable and get that variable on another page. Here what is did is that inside a button tag in onclick I redirected the page to another page(chat.php) with a variable so that when I go to that redirected page I want to see that variable that I passed.Since it is a simple problem I thought I could solve it but even after 3 days I couldn't so this is my last option. Heres my code

```
<button id = 'sendMsg' onclick = "location.href='chat.php?usernames="'.$username.'"'">Send Message</button>
```

This exact line of code works in 'a' tag, idk why.Just to be sure I am uploading all the line without making changes. Heres the a tag code inside php

```
echo "<span id = 'image'><a id = 'accounts' href = 'accounts.php?username=".$username."'><img src = '".$row['photo']."' alt = 'profile photo' width = '100px' height = '100px' style = 'margin-right:40px; margin-top: 5px;'></span>";
```

I am uploading the second code because I want to know the difference as well. And I am wondering why it doesn't work must be because that username that I currently passed is already a variable that I passed in previous page( the a tag is from the previous page) and I get the username using $_GET in this page, which means that the variable that I try to pass in this page is from previous page. Thank You in advance

Comment: missing PHP scriptlets? `onclick="location.href='chat.php?usernames=<?php echo($username); ?>' ">`

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio, it does't get redirected. It acts like it's unclickable(though its clickable)

Comment: Can you please check if `onclick="alert('check');"` actually alerts on click?

Comment: Yeah, it gets alerted.

Comment: what about `onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com/';"` ? Does it redirect?

Comment: You could set a php $_SESSION variable to save your $username on the server
(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm)

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio, yes it does get redirected.

Comment: @Cat, the thing is I already saved a username(my username) when signing up, so whenever I did that all my data got malfunction(does't display like it should, its all in shuffle mode)

Comment: if you are referring to the second snippet, please notice you did not close the a tag:  `</a>` is missing

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio, yeah I close that a tag in the next echo (next line), but will that have anything to do with it? It just doesn't get redirected

Comment: @SangTonsing what is the actual **rendered** HTML for the button ?

Comment: @Cid, can you please write in simple words, I am not very good at vocabularly, and I am also new in coding so I probably won't understand complex words as well

Comment: @SangTonsing Ok :) In the server (php file), you are generating that `<button></button>`. What is the HTML code when you are going to the page ?

Comment: @Cid,echo "TO ".$_GET['usernames']; is the code.

Comment: This is not the HTML code of the button

Comment: <button id = 'sendMsg' onclick="location.href='chat.php?usernames=<?php echo($username); ?>'">Send Message</button>, @cid this one.

Comment: You get the PHP code when you are going to the page?

Comment: @cid, the php code for the redirected page is the one i sent you above -- echo $_GET ---thing, its just a sample to check

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio, thanks it works. Phew...